# Float left checkbox but still want it on the first line of a long text

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I fetch data and put checkbox beside them. It's natural that you put checkbox first before the text, but in my case, because of AJAX fetching, I have to put the checkbox after the fetched text and float it to the left in order to have the checkbox's position goes before the text.

Code would look like this:

```
$a[]=$row['text'].": ".$row['text2']."<input type='checkbox' style='float:left;' name='name' value='$value'><br>";
```

Output would look like this (which is my aim, and think of the bracket as the checkbox):

```
[ ] text: text2 text2 text2
```

It was coded to fetched text before the checkbox, but its output would look like the checkbox were coded before the fetched text, which was my intention.

**My problem** is when a long text would be fetched (that it would produce a new line), it would still stay on the left side of the text, **BUT** it's on the last line of the text. I would like it still to be on the left, but would stay at the first line.

My current output of a long text would look like this:

```
text: text2 text2 text2 text2
[ ] text2 text2 text2 text2 text2
```

As I've said, I need to put the fetched text first on the variable $a[] because of AJAX calling. I can't put the checkbox before the fetched text, because it won't be read by the AJAX.

**UPDATE:** Era's recommendation of no wrap makes the long text looks from this:

```
text: text2 text2 text2 text2 /* long text */
[ ] text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 /* Next line of long text */
[ ] text: text2 text2 text2 (short text) /* New data with short text */
```

into:

```
text: text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 /* long text */
[ ] [ ] text: text2 text2 text2 text2 /* short text */
```

Long text's checkbox went to the short text.

Comment: try to wrap your text in a `div` with `style="white-space: nowrap"`

Comment: @Era I can't put any <> attributes before the $text, because it will ruin the AJAX calling.

Comment: this text and checkbox doesn't have any parent div ?? you can try putting the same css in parent too.

Comment: @Era - Okay. Thanks. But my page contains two div, one on the left and the other one on the right. My ajax is on the left side. And your recommendation of nowrap makes the fetched long text overlap to the right.

Comment: I think the foolproof approach is to wrap your checkbox and label inside a label element, then set the style of the label element to `position: relative; padding-left: 16px;` and set the style of the checkbox to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`. That way you always have your checkbox positioned as you wish.

Comment: Already solved my problem. All I need for the ajax is the first fetched text, (which is short), and what makes the text long is the second fetched text. So what I did is to put the checkbox after the short text and still float it to the left. Solved! Thanks to all of you!